# Sed or Perl Command

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed

I have thousands of data lines like below. This is all in one string. I am looking for a way to only strip the data inside so it only looks like this. " [ActiveOrBackup: ACTIVE]  [Status: OPERATIONAL] " ActiveOrBackUp: Can turn to ACTIVE mode or BACKUP mode. and Status: Can turn to OPERATIONAL and UNREACHABLE. Is this possible ? Thank you.

My strings look like this. $MYSTRING

```
[samplingStatus: OK]  [Version: Wind6.4.0.A4]  [ActiveOrBackup: ACTIVE]  [Status: OPERATIONAL]  [downloads: 0]  [state: OFF]
```

The Result I am aiming for. $AIMRESULT

```
[ActiveOrBackup: ACTIVE]  [Status: OPERATIONAL]
```

or the following when it is a backup server.

```
[ActiveOrBackup: BACKUP]  [Status: OPERATIONAL]
```

My code to grep the string looks like this. This grabs $MYSTRING. I aim to make it look like $AIMRESULT. Is there a perl/awk/sed command that I can pipe into that would let me do this ? Thank you.

```
egrep "name=|sampling" Tmp1.txt > test1 | sed 's/\(.*\)table/table/g' test1 | cut -d "@" -f 4 | cut -d ")" -f 1 > test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "field separator" really is 2 spaced:

```
AIMRESULT=$( perl -F'\s{2}' -lane 'print join "  ", grep {/\[(?:ActiveOrBackup|Status):/} @F' <<< "$MYSTRING" )
```

---

Note, try to get out of the habit of using ALL_CAPS_VARS -- someday you'll write `PATH=/foo/bar` and then wonder why your script is broken.

Comment: Thank you again Glenn. Working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but won't this do it?

```
sed -e "s/^.*ActiveOrBackup: \([A-Z]*\).*Status: \([A-Z]*\).*$/[ActiveOrBackup: \1] [Status: \2]/"
```